# Google Scholar duplicate entries

Tags: citations, google-scholar

It's been a couple of days now since [my Google Scholar profile](https://scholar.google.it/citations?user=O0UONvMAAAAJ&hl=it) has duplicated all my article entries. Indeed, it is listing all my papers in chronological order as it used to, but now if I push the button "show others" at the end of the page, a whole new bunch of duplicate papers appear. I tried to manually merge those duplicates together,  but  this function doesn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I can see this in profiles which I am sure did not show this behaviour before. I just saw one paper that is duplicated five times in a single profile. But the duplication seems to be in the listing on the profile, the entries themselves appear to be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a bug. After a few days, the problem is gone.